# While creating project in Android studio, Gradle sync failing due to this below mentioned error:

Tags: android-studio

After Android Studio(3.4 and 3.2) installation I have tried to create a project. I am getting this error:

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.31.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: blank
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I have set proxy settings in File->settings and gradle properties and Connection successful. I have tried many things through settings still Not working.

Comment: Hi. `from server: blank`? You sure you've set the proxy settings properly?

Comment: Please share the build.gradle file

Comment: yes proxy added properly and while checking Connection , it was successful

Comment: Added gradle file in below image file